# Why can't I save my form data into a model db?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

When I try to save the info inputted into the form, I get the `ValueError`:

`Cannot assign "<class 'auctions.models.User'>": "Listing.user" must be a "User" instance.`

I think that this may be because the model field `Listing.user` is a foreign key between the `Listing` model and the `User` model.

Even when I change `Listing.user = User` to `Listing.user = User()` (includes brackets), it returns the `ValueError`:

`save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'user'.`

So how do I add who the current user is to the model field `Listing.user`?

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Listing(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
def save_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewListing(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = Listing()
            ...
            obj.user = User # this returned the first ValueError
            # obj.user = User() - this returned the second ValueError
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: If you overwritten the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` settings, you could just use `obj.user = self.request.user` - the code will generate one query less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this

```
obj.user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
```

Comment: This is not so far the best solution, `obj.user = self.request.user` is faster because it does not generate another query like `.get()` does (the user is always cached in request if you have overwriten `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.